# Rounding a number in lualatex

Tags: luatex

I've outputted a variable from LuaLatex like so:

```
n = 1.712371273
directlua{tex.print(n)}
```

What's the easiest way to round this number to 2 decimal places?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleRound for example? This feels like a general Lua question ...

Comment: @JosephWright: One could use siunitx ... (if the rounding is for printing) or \fpeval (for all other cases)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sure, but if the focus is on a Lua solution (which seems the case from the question) then those are not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the string formatting provided by Lua.  You have to use `\luaexec` from the `luacode` package to be able to use `%` inside the Lua statement (You still have to escape it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\luaexec{
  n = 1.712371273
  tex.print(string.format("\%.2f",n))
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is the `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucharcat}

\edef\percent{\Uchar`\% 12}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
  n = 1.712371273
  tex.print(string.format("\percent.2f",n))
}

\end{document}
```

This will print

> 1.71